# How to select multiple images when importing textures?

Tags: animation

Is there a way to select multiple textures when applying them to a mesh? I have many maps I'd like to select at once instead of selecting them individually.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what do you mean by "applying images to a mesh" but you can import multiple images for later use.
Just switch to UV/Image editor, click *Open* and select multiple images by any of these methods:

- mouse drag (lasso select)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> for selecting multiple
- or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> for select from the first to the last clicked
  [image]

Comment: I mean applying multiple textures to a material, it's simple. But I'm on a Mac, so I don't know what LMD is